# Is it possible to reuse an alias more than once in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to reuse an alias more than once in MySQL? I need to CONCAT several aliases into a new column (`Ref`). The values from columns `Option`, `Make`, and `Model` have been formulated earlier in my query using CASE statements. The `Ref` column would CONCAT `Qty`, `Option`, `Make` and `Model`. I'm running MySQL version 5.7.29.
Thank you in advance!

```
`Qty` | `Option` | `Make`| `Model` | `Ref` 
******************************************************
1     | Red      | VW    |         | Red / VW
2     | Blue     | POR   |  G4     | 2x Blue / POR  G4
```

**The goal is to re-use an alias (e.g. `Make`) from the CASE statement**

```
CASE
  WHEN `order_product`.`name` LIKE '%Volkswagen%' THEN 'VW'
  WHEN `order_product`.`name` LIKE '%Volvo%' THEN 'VOL'
  ELSE `order_product`.`name`
END AS `Make`,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is some query which produces the output:

```
SELECT {expression1} AS `Qty`,
       {expression2} AS `Option`,
       {expression3} AS `Make`,
       {expression4} AS `Model`
FROM {tableset}
WHERE {conditions}
```

For to obtain the result which you need you must simply usethis query as a subquery:

```
SELECT `Qty`, `Option`, `Make`, `Model`,
       CONCAT ( CASE WHEN `Qty` > 1 
                     THEN CONCAT(`Qty`, 'x ')
                     ELSE ''
                     END,
                `Option`,
                ' / ',
                `Make`,
                CASE WHEN COALESCE(`Model`, '') != ''
                     THEN CONCAT(' ', `Model`)
                     ELSE ''
                     END ) AS `Ref`
FROM ( SELECT {expression1} AS `Qty`,
              {expression2} AS `Option`,
              {expression3} AS `Make`,
              {expression4} AS `Model`
       FROM {tableset}
       WHERE {conditions} ) AS subquery
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=92c99522faeb87b6278a531634b383e9)

Comment: Thank you Akina. Would I put the CASE statement from above inside the {expression3}?

Comment: @msklut "Yes" is more likely than "no".

Comment: Great! It's working like a charm. Thank you so much.